# Web service client: org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jax-ws

we're having a pretty baffling issue here and I wondered if anyone else might know the solution. On Wednesday, a Spring project containing a web service client deployed onto our JBoss application server without incident, and then got invoked without incident as well.

This morning, we tried to deploy a more recent version of the same project, and received this error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServicePort' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create Provider: org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider

My first thought was that there was some kind of change in the server, since I've seen that error before and it had to do with jboss's compatibility or lack thereof with something in java6 I believe. But when we revert to Wednesday's revision in svn, it deploys and runs successfully again. But when we look at the version history, we don't see any changes that could do something like this. There are only two classes that have changed at all that reference the client, and every reference to the client is just how it was before. The application-context.xml and build paths are identical. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Was the project built on a different developer's machine?  Maybe that developer's development environment uses a different version of Spring or Java.  If the project's IDE-related files are version controlled, maybe a change was made to them that would effect how the project is built.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! It definitely did turn out to be something about the one developer's machine who built it that morning.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped!